# check if an event is fired by user click?

Tags: c#, wpf

suppose that I've this function declaration:

```
private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
```

this function can be fired from a user click and inside my code from other functions.
I want check when this function is fired by a user click, how?

Comment: You mean as opposed to the user pressing the 'Spacebar'? Or from other code within your class?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Why do you need to know; how is it going to change what you're going to do?

Comment: I would create a new function called `'ToggleButton(bool userInvoked)` and call this from either the `ToggleButton_Checked` method or the other sources.

Comment: @Aphelion but this is not possible, the function is declared like so in xaml: `Checked="ToggleButton_Checked` The togglebutton are generated via code, so isn't visible in xaml "phisically", when a new button is created the function togglebutton_checked is fired and this is wrong, so I need to check when is fired by the user and when not

Answer (score 0):

A method cannot tell who called it. But here, you have a `sender` argument. If the method gets called by a user click, the sender will be the very `ToggleButton` the user clicked. If you are calling this method in code, pass something different. E.g. the object which makes the call:

```
// Call in code
ToggleButton_Checked(this, e);
```

In `ToggleButton_Checked`:

```
if (sender is ToggleButton) {
    // User click
} else {
    // Called from code
}
```

Note: If you are calling `ToggleButton_Checked`, you are not firing any events, you are just calling an event handler.

---

I think the problem you might have (you didn't explain it) is that you are changing the `Checked` property of your control, but don't want the event handler to be triggered in this case.

You can achieve this by using a guard

```
private bool _changing; // Field
```

Code doing the change:

```
_changing = true;
try {
   myToggleButton.Checked = someNewValue;
} finally {
    _changing = false;
}
```

In the event handler `ToggleButton_Checked`, enclose your code with

```
if (!_changing) {
    // Your code handler stuff.
}
```

Comment: But the question doesn't ask about the case where the method is called as a result of user code, they ask about the case where the event is fired as a result of user code, meaning the sender will still be the button.  Note that if the OP *were* calling the method, rather than firing the event, then the solution would be to have a different method that took a parameter that indicated what it should do differently (rather than an `object` whose runtime type is being checked) as a way of accomplishing that.

Comment: Is it possible to fire an event of another class? I don't think it is possible to fire an event of the `TogleButton` from outside. You can set the `Checked` property from outside.

Comment: Not explicitly.  You can perform an action that will result in that class choosing to fire the event (namely, by checking it, in the case of a `Checked` event).

Comment: @Servy: This might be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Indeed, that's why I asked for more context instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can take away the need for your question altogether, by simply not invoking events from user code.

Event handlers exist to ... handle events. So extract the logic from the event  into its own method:

```
private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoTheThing(userInitiated: true);
}

private void DoTheThing(bool userInitiated)
{
    if (userInitiated)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then you can call the same method from code:

```
DoTheThing(userInitiated: false);
```